# Using a list view in a custom dialogue

Tags: android, listview

How would I use a list in this custom dialogue? ive set a list int the .xml of the listview but am unfamiliar with how to use it properly (I want the values for the list to come from a string array)

My main java:

```
package custom.dialouge.list;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomDialougeListTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context mContext = this;
    final Context context = this;
    Button button;



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {


        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list);
        dialog.setTitle("List");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        text.setText("Test");

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
      }
    });

}
}
```

My custom dialouge .xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is listview in your code `.java file ....add it first...`

Comment: Thats one of the things i need help implemanting, listview is something ive never used before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> myStringArray = ... // insert your code to get/create the array here
ListView view = dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);
view.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Like so:

```
public class CustomDialougeListTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context mContext = this;
    final Context context = this;
    Button button;

    ArrayList<String> myStringArray = ... // insert your code to get/create the array here
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {


        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list);
        dialog.setTitle("List");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        text.setText("Test");

        ListView view = dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        view.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
      }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: would i just place this in my main activity?

Comment: You could place it wherever you have a reference to your dialog.  It could conceivably fit in your `onCreate`.

Comment: Would you be able to quickly so me how you would place this into my code? list view really confuses me

Comment: Its erroring when i try to get my array via res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray)

Comment: That will need to be a `String[]` then, not an `ArrayList<String>`.  Post the error if you would like help debugging it.